# How to depend on a large Database in NodeJS NPM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

NPM is not made for large files. My NPM package contains a **800MB SQLite database**. I thought I could easily keep it out of the package tarball and [require it via URL dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#urls-as-dependencies).

But this dependency rule has to be used for a download of another NPM package tarball. So I will end with just another NPM tarball containing the 800MB database. By keeping it out of the package I would have to put it in another package.

Is this a bad usage of NPM and if yes, what is the best way to install the database file? Important is that **NPM takes care of the proper installation** and only installs the package if it contains the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you

- publish module A in npm
- A depends on module B as a URL dependency
- You host B yourself at a publicly accessible url

you are not abusing npm registry at all.

Only individual users that choose to use your package A will ever download B, but A is available in npm registry for all to find & make use of.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. But on my local machine, B looks like any other package and bloats the directory. This is no problem, you think?